# Virtualbox and Windows

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I am trying to install windows 7 through virtualbox on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I am unable to install it as everytime on the virtual machine it asks me to load drivers.
I am made to understand that the drivers of windows 7 are integrated in the CD/DVD wich is used for installation. 
PLease help me out...

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need to install the VirtualBox Extension Pack that is relevant to your version of VB. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads - hope this works for you.